# Celery task not starting at the start time provided

Tags: django, celery, python-3.7, celerybeat

I have a Django app that utilizes celery in order to handle user scheduled tasks. I'm currently having a problem where I set start time for the PerodicTask and it does not start at that specific time, rather sometime later instead.

Environment:

- Celery 4.3
- Django 2.2
- Python 3.7

```py
task = PeriodicTask(name="foo",task="bar_task",
                    start_time=DateTime5MinutesAhead, 
                    interval=EveryHourInterval)
task.save()
```

I expect the task run first in 5 minutes from when the task was created and then every hour after that. Instead, it seems to run at some arbitrary point later, completely ignoring the `start_time` argument.

Am I mistaken on what the `start_time` argument is for?

I've tried with `IntervalSchedule` as well as `CrontabSchedule`

and neither seem to start at the exact start time.

**Bonus:** What's actually really weird in my findings is that if I use `IntervalSchedule` set to every **minute** it actually **DOES**, in fact, start on correctly and run correctly, but if I set it to anything else it no longer works.

Comment: it might not have started at the right time. but the per minute schedule made it to run giving a feeling of starting on time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to set `last_run_at` to `start_time` - `interval`

```
        task = PeriodicTask(name="foo",task="bar_task",
                start_time=DateTime5MinutesAhead,
                last_run_at=DateTime5MinutesAhead - timedelta(hour=1),
                interval=EveryHourInterval)
        task.save()
```

not sure if its a bug or a feature but worked fine for me,

reference:
https://github.com/celery/django-celery-beat/issues/259